# InMemoryWebAPI does not return JSON data

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I am tackling the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/) tutorial in Angular. The problem I am facing is with InMemoryWebAPI setup. The files involved are the following:

*in-memory-data.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes : Hero[] = [
      { id: 12, name: 'Dr. Nice' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr. IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }

  // Overrides the genId method to ensure that a hero always has an id.
  // If the heroes array is empty,
  // the method below returns the initial number (11).
  // if the heroes array is not empty, the method below returns the highest
  // hero id + 1.
  genId(heroes: Hero[]): number {
    return heroes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...heroes.map(hero => hero.id)) + 1 : 11;
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroSearchComponent } from './hero-search/hero-search.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import {RouterLink} from "@angular/router";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterLink,
    // The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
    // and returns simulated server responses.
    // Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests.
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, {dataEncapsulation: false}
    )
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The error message I get is the following:

> HeroService: getHeroes failed: Http failure during parsing for
> http://localhost:4200/api/heroes

I am trying to understand the reason for this error, as well as any possibilities of solving the issue. According to the tutorial, it should return the heroes array from GET request.

I am guessing one possible explanation is that InMemoryDataService does not load as expected in Angular. Another possible explanation could be that there might be some bug in the code, in the way that elements are registered.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The provided code seems fine to me. Only problem I notice is you do not need to import `RouterLink` in the `imports` array of `app.module.ts`

Kindly find below a reference stackblitz for the `tour of heroes - modular version` for your reference and to cross check your code!

If you are still not able to solve the issue please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated or the github repo for debugging!

[Stackblitz Demo (Not By Me!)](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/markmals/angular-tour-of-heroes-modernized)

[Modernized tour of heroes github repo](https://github.com/markmals/angular-tour-of-heroes-modernized)